# Angular. Mi validacion personalizada no funciona ( Comparar password y repeat_password)

Tags: angular, formularios, validación, angular7

estoy haciendo una validacion personalizada para mi formulario:

El validator para mi **formGroup** es este :

```
 this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
        name:['',[
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(3),
        ]],
        email:['',[
          Validators.required,
          Validators.email
        ]],
        password:['',[
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(8),
          Validators.maxLength(16)
        ]],
        repeat_password:['',[
          Validators.required
        ]],
        validators:this.checkPasswords('password','repeat_password')
      });
```

En principio, todas las validacion funcionan bien, menos la ultima (`checkPasswords`), que sirve para verficar que el campo `repeat_password` sea igual a `password` basicamente. Esta validacion personalizada esta compuesta de la siguiente manera:

```
  checkPasswords(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
      const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

      if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
        // return if another validator has already found an error on the matchingControl
        return;
      }

      // set error on matchingControl if validation fails
      if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
        matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
      } else {
        matchingControl.setErrors(null);
      }
    }}
```

En la vista, este campo de repetir contraseña esta asi:

```
   <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Repeat password" formControlName="repeat_password">
          <div class="mt-3" *ngIf=" registerForm.get('repeat_password').errors && registerForm.get('repeat_password').dirty">
            <small  class="custom_error" *ngIf="registerForm.get('repeat_password').errors.required" >Error ! :  <span> El campo es requerido</span></small>
            <small  class="custom_error" *ngIf="registerForm.get('repeat_password').errors.mustMatch" >Error ! :  <span> Las contraseñas no coinciden</span></small>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-3">
            <small class="custom_success" *ngIf="registerForm.get('repeat_password').valid && registerForm.get('repeat_password').dirty" ><span> OK!</span></small>
          </div>
        </div>
```

No funciona, los demas validators que vienen por defecto como required si lo hacen bien. He mirado tutoriales y lo he hecho basandome en ellos. Deberia de existir un error con el nombre `mustMatch` si ambos controls no coinciden y mostrar el mensaje que le tengo puesto.

¿Alguien sabe donde puede estar fallando esto?

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
 checkPasswords: ValidatorFn = (
    control: AbstractControl
  ): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const password = control.get("password");
    const password_repeat = control.get("password_repeat");
    
    //Comprobamos unicamente
    return password &&
      password_repeat &&
      password.value !== password_repeat.value
      ? { passwordCoincide: false }
      : null;
  };

  formulario = new FormGroup(
    {
      password: new FormControl("", Validators.minLength(2)),
      password_repeat: new FormControl("", Validators.minLength(2))
    },
    //El segundo parametro son opciones, y entre ellas esta validator. 
    { validators: [this.checkPasswords] }
  );
}
```

Ahora las validaciones las obtienes en el global del formualrio asi [html] :

```
{{formulario.errors | json }}
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nnl9pn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

> ## Validaciones cruzadas
>
> Mas sobre las validaciones cruzadas
> [aquí](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-cross-validation-to-reactive-forms).